# Next.js autoloading is slow on docker

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-volume, hot-reload

I use [official Next.js Dockerfile](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/769d27aaccf34a6a32158725211b51f869b3ea2f/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile) to dockerize my Next.js based application.
I use the following volumes in my `docker-compose.yml` to enable autoloader.

Unfortunately in both Mac and Windows autoloader is too slow and it takes a few second to reflect changes. Is there any docker solution without additional tools such as docker-sync?

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./app:/app
  # # Prevent the following directories from being mounted over by line above
  - ./app/node_modules
  - ./app/.next
```

I have also tried `./app:/app:delegated` volume

##### .dockerignore

```
.next
node_modules
```

Comment: Why do you actually need Docker here?  Can you use plain Node, and avoid the performance costs of crossing in and out of an isolated filesystem?

Comment: I need docker to simplify installation steps, several projects work together and this is why docker exists